# Need a second \end{choices} for exam class with pgf foreach?

Tags: exam, pgffor

I cannot figure out the reason for this weird occurrence.
If I declare my exam to print answers, I get an error that

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{choices} on input line 21 ended by \end{questions}
! LaTeX Error: \begin{questions} on input line 20 ended by \end{document}.
```

This is fixed, if I simply add a second line of

```
\end{choices}
```

To my newcommand. If I am not printing answers, the second `\end{choices}` is not required.

What am I writing improperly for the loop that is making it ignore the first `\end{choices}`?

I have included all the lines needed in my MWE, but I have commented out the print answers part and the 2nd `\end{choices}` so you can see it compile and work properly as well.

```
% to see the error in action, comment this first documentclass command, and uncomment the one with [answers]
% to resolve the error generated when enabling the answers, uncomment the second \end{choices} command down in \newcommand{\newmpchoice}
\documentclass{exam}
%\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\printchoice}[3]{\ifnum\numexpr#1\relax=\numexpr#2\relax \CorrectChoice #3 \else \choice #3\fi}

\newcommand{\newmpchoice}[4]{
\question #1
\begin{choices}
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {#3}
{   \printchoice{#2}{\xi}{\x}};
\end{choices}
%\end{choices}
\begin{solution}
#4
\end{solution}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\newmpchoice{Test question}{1}{{Answer 1},{Answer 2},{Answer 3},{Answer 4},{Answer 5}}{Solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: running your code with a single `\end{choice}` works fine here. I get the error you describe if I add two of them. Unless I am misinterpreting something here.

Comment: At the top, if you switch out the documentclass commands, and use the one with "answers" in it, it should give you an error without the second `\end{choice}` in it. I've added a comment to the top of the code to make that more clear

Comment: @RunarTrollet I do appreciate you looking into it!

Comment: Have a look at the coumentation (commandline `texdoc exam`, or http://ctan.org/pkg/exam ), section **3.2 The option answers ** which specifies some changes. The problem has something to to with `\CorrectChoice`, but I cannot look into it further right now.

Comment: @RunarTrollet Yes, I am aware of that section, that just describes what the "answers" option does, which is what I want. If I do not use a forloop, and list my options normally, then it works fine

Comment: @RunarTrollet That works perfect, if you write up an answer, I can mark it as solved with that solution

Comment: I removed my comment, as the code could possibly break stuff. See egregs solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual issue with `\foreach`, that executes each cycle in a group and this breaks the `\CorrectChoice` settings, that are forgotten as soon as the cycle ends and the group is closed.

You can do it more easily with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass[
  answers % comment this line for not showing answers
]{exam}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newmpchoice}{mmmm}
 {
  \question #1
  \begin{choices}
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \int_compare:nTF { #2 = \value{choice}+1 } { \CorrectChoice } { \choice }
    ##1
   }
  \end{choices}
  \begin{solution}
  #4
  \end{solution}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\newmpchoice{Test question}{1}{{Answer 1},{Answer 2},{Answer 3},{Answer 4},{Answer 5}}{Solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I use the fact that the `choice` counter is incremented at each `\choice` or `\CorrectChoice` command (and reset to zero at `\begin{choices}`), so before one of these commands its value is one less than needed for the comparison.

[image]

You can also do it with `\foreach`, but in this case you have to collect the bits in some macro that you can then deliver.

```
\documentclass[
  answers % comment this line for not showing solutions
]{exam}
\usepackage{pgffor,etoolbox}

\newcommand{\newmpchoice}[4]{%
  \question #1
  \begin{choices}
  \def\thesechoices{}%
  \foreach \x[count=\xi] in {#3} {%
    \ifnum\numexpr#2\relax=\numexpr\xi\relax
       \xappto\thesechoices{\noexpand\CorrectChoice\expandonce{\x}}%
    \else
       \xappto\thesechoices{\noexpand\choice\expandonce{\x}}%
    \fi
  }%
  \thesechoices
  \end{choices}
  \begin{solution}
  #4
  \end{solution}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\newmpchoice{Test question}{1}{{Answer 1},{Answer 2},{Answer 3},{Answer 4},{Answer 5}}{Solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

---

You can also accommodate more than one correct answer, with a modification of the first solution:

```
\documentclass[
  answers % comment this line for not showing answers
]{exam}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newmpchoice}{mmmm}
 {
  \question #1
  \begin{choices}
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \clist_if_in:nxTF { #2 } { \int_to_arabic:n { \value{choice} + 1 } }
     { \CorrectChoice } { \choice }
    ##1
   }
  \end{choices}
  \begin{solution}
  #4
  \end{solution}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_if_in:nnTF { nx }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\newmpchoice{Test question}{1}{{Answer 1},{Answer 2},{Answer 3},{Answer 4},{Answer 5}}{Solution}
\newmpchoice{Test question}{1, 3}{{Answer 1},{Answer 2},{Answer 3},{Answer 4},{Answer 5}}{Solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @egreg would it be possible for this to be modified to accept multiple amount of correct answers? Correct choices would be comma separated (or whatever else was easier)`\newmpchoice{question}{1,3}{{Answer 1 - is correct},{Answer 2},{Answer 3 - is correct},{Answer 4},{Answer 5}}{Solution}`

Comment: @JM Easy enough. `;-)`