# Atomic electronic configuration with small boxes

Tags: boxes, chemistry

I need to create a new command for the electronic distribution of an atom (orbitals S, P, D, F), similar to the one shown in the link below, but with boxes around the electron pairs.
Can someone help me please?

[Electron Configuration Diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340443/electron-configuration-diagram)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you mean something like in [this picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VabYm.png)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I adapted the solution from the attached link, to draw an `\fbox` instead of `\underline`. In addition, I had to add `\mathord` to make the `\fbox`-es across the definitions to have equal widths. (not sure if I did this right though)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for harpoons
\newcommand{\electron}[2]{{%
        \newcommand*\up{\fbox{$\mathord\upharpoonleft\phantom{\downharpoonright}$}}%
        \newcommand*\dwn{\fbox{$\mathord\downharpoonleft\phantom{\upharpoonright}$}}%
        \newcommand*\updwn{\fbox{$\upharpoonleft\downharpoonright$}}%
        \newcommand*\emp{\fbox{$\phantom{\downharpoonright}\phantom{\downharpoonright}$}}%
        \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}% remove extra horizontal space from tabular
        \begin{tabular}{c}#2\\[2pt]#1\end{tabular}%
}}
\begin{document}
    \electron{2s}{\updwn}\quad \electron{2p}{\up\ \dwn\ \emp}
\end{document}
```

[image: boxed]

The commands:

- `\up`: up spin electron only
- `\dwn`: down spin electron only
- `\updwn`: up and down spin electrons (filled)
- `\emp`: no electrons (unfilled)

---

**Edit:**

Updated code for the boxes to be attached to each other, with equal line widths. Usage is still the same as above. The lines are thicker now because *two* `fbox`-es are being drawn. If you want to stick to the old `fbox` line width, uncomment the `\setlength\fboxrule{0.2pt}` line.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for harpoons
\newcommand*\up{\fbox{$\mathord\upharpoonleft\phantom{\downharpoonright}$}}%
\newcommand*\dwn{\fbox{$\mathord\downharpoonleft\phantom{\upharpoonright}$}}%
\newcommand*\updwn{\fbox{$\upharpoonleft\downharpoonright$}}%
\newcommand*\emp{\fbox{$\phantom{\downharpoonright}\phantom{\downharpoonright}$}}%
\newcommand{\electron}[2]{{%
        \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}% remove extra horizontal space from tabular
%       \setlength\fboxrule{0.2pt}% uncomment for original line width
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\fboxsep=3pt#2}\\[2pt]
            #1
        \end{tabular}%
}}
\begin{document}
    \electron{2s}{\updwn}\quad \electron{2p}{\up\dwn\emp}
\end{document}
```

[image: update box]

Comment: is possible obtain p-boxes and d-boxes glued together?

Comment: You mean like `\electron{2s}{\updwn}\electron{2p}{\up\ \dwn\ \emp}` or `\electron{2s}{\updwn}\quad \electron{2p}{\up\dwn\emp}`?

Comment: More like the second option, but with lines of the same thickness

Comment: @EdsonMarcon see update.

Comment: @EdsonMarcon If it answers your question, please consider accepting my answer by clicking the green tick next to the answer. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](//$SITEURL$/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 8):

Why reinvent the wheel.  Use `modiagram`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{modiagram}
\begin{document}

\begin{MOdiagram}[style=square]
  \AO{s}[label={2s}]{0}
  \AO(30pt){p}[label[y]={2p}]{0;up,up,up}
\end{MOdiagram}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or without `style=square`

[image]

Comment: is possible obtain p-boxes and d-boxes glued together?

Comment: @EdsonMarcon Actually no, which is quite surprising.  The distance between the boxes is hardcoded in `modiagram.sty`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an adaptation of my answer to accommodate both styles (box or underline):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\electron}{smm}
 { % #2 = level, #3 = electron schemes
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \jm_electron:Nnn \underline { #2 } { #3 } }
   { \jm_electron:Nnn \fbox { #2 } { #3 } }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_jm_electron_schemes_seq
\seq_new:N \l__jm_electron_schemes_print_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jm_electron:Nnn
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__jm_electron_highlight:n #1
  \seq_clear:N \l__jm_electron_schemes_print_seq
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_jm_electron_schemes_seq { | } { #3 }
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_jm_electron_schemes_seq \__jm_electron_do_scheme:n
  % print the schemes
  \group_begin:
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.2em}
  \begin{tabular}{ * { \seq_count:N \l_jm_electron_schemes_seq } { c } }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__jm_electron_schemes_print_seq { & } \\
  \multicolumn { \seq_count:N \l_jm_electron_schemes_seq } { c } { #2 }
  \end{tabular}
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jm_electron_do_scheme:n
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l__jm_electron_schemes_print_seq
   {
    \__jm_electron_highlight:n
     {
      \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
       {
        \int_case:nn { ##1 }
         {
          {1}{$\scriptstyle\upharpoonleft$}
          {0}{\phantom{$\scriptstyle\upharpoonleft$}}
          {-1}{$\scriptstyle\downharpoonright$}
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\electron{2s}{1,-1}\quad\electron{2p}{1,0 | 1,0 | 1,0}

\electron*{2s}{1,-1}\quad\electron*{2p}{1,0 | 1,0 | 1,0}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I made changes in your original code to obtain p-boxes and d-boxes  glued together, but the corners isn't goods.                  \begin{tabular}{ * { \seq_count:N \l_jm_electron_schemes_seq } { |c }| }
   \hline
  \seq_use:Nn \l__jm_electron_schemes_print_seq { & } \\ \hline
  \multicolumn { \seq_count:N \l_jm_electron_schemes_seq } { c } { #1 }
  \end{tabular}